# Web scrapting of image with Python

Tags: python, list, image, exception, web-scraping

I am learning Python language and the code below saves images from a URL's list. But I would like ignore when URL isn't an image and save .png formate, too.

```
import pandas as pd
import urllib.request

def url_to_jpg(i, url, file_path):


    filename = 'image-{}.jpg'.format(i)

    full_path = '{}{}'.format(file_path, filename)
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, full_path)

    return None

FILENAME = 'C:/Users/Home/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/Start Menu/Programs/Python 3.8/image_url.csv'
FILE_PATH = 'C:/Users/Home/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/Start Menu/Programs/Python 3.8/imagens2/'

urls = pd.read_csv(FILENAME)

for i, url in enumerate(urls.values):
    url_to_jpg(i, url[0], FILE_PATH)
```

Comment: If you are doing web scraping you should use https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the headers content-type

```
import urllib
request = urllib.request.urlretrieve('https://www.jhsph.edu/sebin/j/k/public-health-on-call.jpg')

request[1].__dict__
```

you will see that the urlretrieve method returns  a tuple, second element is:

```
{'_charset': None,
 '_default_type': 'text/plain',
 '_headers': [('Server', 'nginx/1.17.6'),
  ('Date', 'Sat, 04 Apr 2020 22:00:21 GMT'),
  ('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg'),
  ('Content-Length', '129747'),
  ('Connection', 'close'),
  ('Last-Modified', 'Wed, 04 Mar 2020 15:26:43 GMT'),
  ('ETag', '"3632864f39f2d51:0"'),
  ('X-Powered-By', 'ASP.NET'),
  ('Accept-Ranges', 'bytes')],
 '_payload': '',
 '_unixfrom': None,
 'defects': [],
 'epilogue': None,
 'policy': Compat32(),
 'preamble': None}
```

Content-Type tells you that is an image and the type of image. So based on that you can decide how to save it, and what to do.